# Python main function

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I came across a line in python:

```
def somefunc:
    [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    somefunc
```

I don't understand what the "if __name ..." does.

Suppose we have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': main()

#this code will find main
```

So is this similar to the main() function in C/C++, which gets executed before any other function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can think this as the main() in C or the BEGIN { } block in perl.

when you run the code using python file1.py.

`__name__` in file1.py is equal to `'__main__'`,  but in other files imported  by file1.py, the variable is something else.

Answer (score 9):

If you execute your script directly, without importing it, `__name__` will be equal to `__main__`. But if you import this file, `__name__` will be equal to the name of the module importing it.
This condition makes sure you execute your code from this file.